# Is there a way to verify client with curl?

Tags: php

I'm making a client/server application with php.

The server takes an array serializes and echos the result.

the server could be hosted at www.site1.com/server.php

```
echo serialize($array);
```

The client could be hosted at www.site2.com/client.php

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.site1.com/server.php');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

What I'm trying to do is to make server.php only echo the information iff the client is from www.site2.com/client.php.

Something like

```
iff('Client is from www.site2.com/client.php'){
  echo curl_exec($ch)
} else {
  exit();
}
```

site2 does not have SSL

What variable do i look up, or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

client.php

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.site1.com/server.php?supersecretpassword');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

server.php

```
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] === "supersecretpassword"){
  echo curl_exec($ch)
} else {
  exit();
}
```

As additional security measure you can check in server.php if $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is equal to the IP address of the computer your client.php is on.

Comment: Isn't that vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks without SSL?

Comment: @DanMan - Yes, it is. To prevent that you could just encrypt response with triple des or blowfish or whatever since client and server can have shared secret.

Answer (score 1):

If the client has a fixed IP, you could reverse DNS the client and see if the IP is correct. No idea how reliable that is though. I'm not into black arts - that path leads to the dark side.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to accurately secure communications as you describe. The real security-minded answer to your question is to set up a firewall.